# How to properly add padding to the plot area in a D3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a line chart in D3 as seen here:

[image: Line chart with incorrect x-axis size]

I am attempting to extend the x-axis to be the same size as the y-axis tick width. Currently I am setting the ranges as follows:

```
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([20, width - 20]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
```

This achieves my desired effect of pushing the plot in from the left and right sides but does not extend the x-axis. I'm sure there has to be a way to add padding to the plot without changing the ranges but I can't seem to figure out how?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to add padding to a linear scale.

However, in your case, since your x axis is presenting categorical data (days of the week), you can use a [`d3.scalePoint`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#point-scales) and configure its outer padding with the [`padding` function](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#point_padding).